# Want to upgrade my database class written in mysql*. What should I use next?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

I'm a mid level developer and until today, I had a database class using depracated mysql* functions that I coded few years ago. I want to upgrade it, but before I pick something, I wanted to get opinion of stackoverflow.

I had two options before. MySQLi and PDO. Recently, a senior developer told me to remove my database class completely, learn Doctrine DBAL and use it.

I don't know alot about Doctrine DBAL. Is it something would be overkill for my mini framework?

What should I pick and use, and why?

Comment: btw, I'd suggested to use `doctrine` tag instead of neutral `database`. You'd have a chance to get opinion from other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the good question.

First, on MySQLi vs. PDO question.
In case you're looking for the new base for your own class

- if you're going to use native prepared statements, PDO is the only choice, as mysqli's implementation for them is horrible.
- if you already have your own placeholders in the old mysql based class - mysqli would be easier for transition.

In case you're looking for the completely new class, PDO again is the only choice, as it has some abstraction features, making it's use a lot easier and, producing dramatically shorter code. Recently I wrote a [wiki for the PDO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) explaining some of it's features (as well as pitfalls) - you may find it useful.
However, it lacks many important features. So, a hand-made helper class is still the best choice.

If you don't have placeholders implemented already, I'd suggest you a ready-made class, as placeholders have to be main reason for such a class.
I've made [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) keeping in mind 3 goals: safety, DRY code and ease of use.
I hope you'd like the idea of type-hinted placeholders.

As for the Doctrine - personally I don't like *such* level of abstraction. I prefer to keep as close to SQL as possible. With only a few helpers for the safety and lesser code.

A note on all that performance stuff.
I've never seen an application where DBAL would be a bottleneck. 
So, whatever (imaginary) performance issues have to be your least concern.
A real-life profining on a live environment with actual data is the only reliable proof.

Answer (score 2):

PDO is perfectly fine. Doctrine is bloated and slow. I've had nothing but horrid experiences with it, and can't find any good reason to use it over PDO. DBAL != ORM by the way. DBAL is the DB abstraction layer. PDO is the data access layer. Regardless, PDO is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason in the world not to use MySqli or PDO - whichever one you feel most comfortable with.

IMHO...

PS:
I've never heard of "Doctrine DBAL" either :)

PPS:
Another abstraction layer often means more bloat, diminished performance, and reduced flexibility.  To say nothing of the learning curve.  All very good reasons to stick with PDO or MySqli.

Answer (score 0):

If this for MySQL only, use mysqli as it is slightly (slightly means up to 10 %) faster compared to PDO. If you want to use the extra features of Doctrine DBAL like transations or type conversion you can try it out. If not, stay with PDO as it is a lot faster (up to 10 times) and uses less memory compared to Doctrine DBAL.

Comment: Hi, Oliver.  You're absolutely correct.  I have no idea what twit downvoted you - but thank you for your reply.

Comment: mysqli is 10% faster than PDO which is 10x faster? wut?

Comment: @Your Common Sense - I understand Oliver to be saying that MySqli is slightly faster than PDO, and both of them are a lot faster than DBAL.  That's true - I agree with him.  IMHO...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, it's late here. :-)

Comment: I hope you have a real life proof for such a big numbers

Comment: http://vincent-lecomte.blogspot.nl/2011/01/web-php-zend-benchmark-pdo-vs-doctrine.html My tests on doctrine2 wasn't that bad.

Comment: The source doesn't seem reliable to me.

Comment: @CommonSense - don't quibble.  It's a documented fact that 90% of all statistics are made up on the fly :)